# Create a data connection from MS Project Server to Excel 2007

Tags: vba, ms-project, data-connections, ms-project-server-2013

Hi I have a Project plan which sits on MS Project Server. What would be the easiest way for me to create a data connection which isn't just a one time refresh from Project to Excel with the use of VBA?

I could obviously take an extract manually each time from MS Project to Excel but wondering if there is anything I can use to automate this via a Data Connection in Excel?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an Excel data connection which uses an identity from the securestore (as described [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh525342.aspx)) and then query the project server database (some sample queries [here](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/projectserver/Server-20072010-SQL-Get-a99d4bc6))